Pass states of master class to worker in another process
I want to share a state of a master class over multiple workers. To achieve this I created a Master and Worker class. The worker is triggered by a simple button that is tracked by eel.
My worker increases a internal state each second and can return the state via a method.
import multiprocessing
import time


class Master:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 0
        self.state = {}
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def calculate(self):
        while True:
            self.number += 1
            with self.lock:
                # Calculate dicts and save them into the state
                self.state = {"data": self.number}
            time.sleep(1)

    def get_state(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.state

My Worker class is initialized with a master class takes data from a queue, gets the current state of the master and prints it.
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, master, cpu_id):
        self.master = master
        self.busy = False

    def process(self, data, queue_size):
        print(f"Queue size: {queue_size}")
        self.busy = True
        state = self.master.get_state()
        # Process the data using the state and the unique CPU
        print(f"Processing {[x - self.cpu_id for x in data]} using state {state} on CPU {self.cpu_id}")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.busy = False

def worker_process(worker, queue):
    while True:
        if not queue.empty():
            data = queue.get()
            worker.process(data, queue.qsize())


def main():
    master = Master()
    workers = [Worker(master, i) for i in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count())]

    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    for worker in workers:
        multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_process, args=(worker, queue)).start()

    master_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=master.calculate)
    master_process.start()

    eel_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_eel, args=(queue,))
    eel_process.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


My problem is that the state isn't changed after initialization of the worker. From my research Python doesn't pass the master by reference. Therefore it initializes an own master class which isn't startet and therefore unchanged. I also thought about global variables in a config file containing a queue. But how can each worker differentiate which output in the queue belongs to the specific get_state() call? If multiple workers call the states and these are passed into the queue, do I also need to pass a worker ID so I can select the specific element in the queue? Unfortunately research2 didn't help me either.

Parameters passed to subprocesses are serialised (pickle) such that each process gets its own copy. Any changes made to that object in a subprocess will not be visible in other processes. Use a database or serialise/deserialise the object in your own code.

If you truly need to store your state as a dictionary (that's not the case with the code you posted since there is only a single value in self.state that is being updated) and you need for it to be shareable across processes, then I would recommend using a managed dictionary.
I have found several other issues with your code, so please read the comments I have added that start with 'Booboo'
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time


class Master:
    def __init__(self, managed_dict):
        self.number = 0
        self.state = managed_dict
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def calculate(self):
        while True:
            self.number += 1
            with self.lock:
                # Calculate dicts and save them into the state
                self.state.update({"data": self.number})
            time.sleep(1)

    def get_state(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.state

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, master, cpu_id):
        self.master = master
        self.cpu_id = cpu_id  # Booboo - This was missiing
        self.busy = False

    def process(self, data, queue_size):
        print(f"Queue size: {queue_size}")
        self.busy = True
        state = self.master.get_state()
        # Process the data using the state and the unique CPU
        print(f"Processing {[x - self.cpu_id for x in data]} using state {state} on CPU {self.cpu_id}")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.busy = False

def worker_process(worker, queue):
    while True:
        # Booboo - queue.empty is not reliable and you are burning
        # needless CPU cycles testing it:
        data = queue.get()  # Booboo - just block until data is available
        # Booboo - Warning: queue.qsize() is unreliable
        worker.process(data, queue.qsize())


# Booboo - Missing start_eel function

def start_eel(queue):
    for i in range(100, 121):
        queue.put([i, i])
        time.sleep(.5)

def main():
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        managed_dict = manager.dict()
        master = Master(managed_dict)
        workers = [Worker(master, i) for i in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count())]

        queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

        for worker in workers:
            # Booboo - Make these daemon processes so that they will automatically
            # terminate when the main process terminates
            multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_process, args=(worker, queue), daemon=True).start()

        # Booboo - make daemon:
        master_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=master.calculate, daemon=True)
        master_process.start()

        # Booboo - start_eel is not defined, so I will define it
        eel_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_eel, args=(queue,))
        eel_process.start()
        # Booboo - So that we eventually terminate.
        # If this process hasn't completed in 10 seconds,
        # we will quit anyway:
        eel_process.join(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Prints:
Queue size: 0
Processing [99, 99] using state {'data': 1} on CPU 1
Queue size: 0
Processing [98, 98] using state {'data': 1} on CPU 3
Queue size: 0
Processing [102, 102] using state {'data': 2} on CPU 0
Queue size: 0
Processing [98, 98] using state {'data': 2} on CPU 5
Queue size: 0
Processing [100, 100] using state {'data': 3} on CPU 4
Queue size: 0
Processing [103, 103] using state {'data': 3} on CPU 2
Queue size: 0
Processing [99, 99] using state {'data': 4} on CPU 7
Queue size: 0
Processing [101, 101] using state {'data': 4} on CPU 6
Queue size: 0
Processing [107, 107] using state {'data': 5} on CPU 1
Queue size: 0
Processing [106, 106] using state {'data': 5} on CPU 3
Queue size: 0
Processing [110, 110] using state {'data': 6} on CPU 0
Queue size: 0
Processing [106, 106] using state {'data': 6} on CPU 5
Queue size: 0
Processing [108, 108] using state {'data': 7} on CPU 4
Queue size: 0
Processing [111, 111] using state {'data': 7} on CPU 2
Queue size: 0
Processing [107, 107] using state {'data': 8} on CPU 7
Queue size: 0
Processing [109, 109] using state {'data': 8} on CPU 6
Queue size: 0
Processing [115, 115] using state {'data': 9} on CPU 1
Queue size: 0
Processing [114, 114] using state {'data': 9} on CPU 3
Queue size: 0
Processing [118, 118] using state {'data': 10} on CPU 0
Queue size: 0
Processing [114, 114] using state {'data': 10} on CPU 5


I would recommend sharing the state of your master class explicitly by using a shared memory object. That way, all changes made to this object are instantly visible to all other process when they attempt to read that object.
Since your state is a simple counter, you should be happy with a 'Value'-type shared memory object.
Here is a very simple example of two processes. One is changing the variable and the second only reads it:
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array
import time, random

def writer(n):
    n.value = random.random()

def reader(n):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(n.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)

    p = Process(target=reader, args=(num,), daemon=True)
    p.start()
    q = Process(target=writer, args=(num,), daemon=True)
    q.start()

    p.join()
    q.join()

Read this pyhton docu for more information.
